# Hibernate query for objects with collections

Tags: hibernate

For a structure as follows:

```
class Person
{
   Integer personID;
   String personName
   List<Pet> pets;
}

class Pet
{
  String petID;
  Integer personID;
  String petName;
  Integer petNum;
}
```

The above is stored in the db as follows:

```
person_ID  person Name 
1            Peter
2            Buch
3            POLR

pet_id  person id petName petNum
1         1        "AAA"    3
2         1        "BBB"    3
3         1        "CCC"    4
```

I want to be able to search for Persons based on the person name and the pets he owns. So the input to the Hibernate query could be following:

```
person name = Peter
petName = "AAA"
petNum = 3
petName = "BBB"
petNum = 4
```

So in the above case, it should not return back any results because the serach did not specify the other pet that Peter has.

is a search such as this possible with HQL or Criteria API of Hibernate?

Thanks,
Nishanth

Comment: Changed wording from "Hibernate Search", since this refers to a whole other can of worms (http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/search.html)

Answer (score 0):

I believe such kind of a search is possible.

with Criteria API try something like this:

```
 getSession().createCriteria(Person.class)
    .addRestriction(Restrictions.eq("name", personName)
    .createAlias("pets","pets")
    .addRestriction(Restrictions.eq("pets.name", petName))
    .list();
```